# CycleAvoidingMapperContext cleanup in Mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

In Mapstruct discussions and examples CycleAvoidingMapperContext usage was introduced in order to actually avoid cycle dependencies.

```
@Component
public class CycleAvoidingMappingContext {
    private Map<Object, Object> knownInstances = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Object>();

    @BeforeMapping
    public <T> T getMappedInstance(Object source, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
        return (T) knownInstances.get( source );
    }

    @BeforeMapping
    public void storeMappedInstance(Object source, @MappingTarget Object target) {
        knownInstances.put( source, target );
    }
}
```

My mapper uses componentModel = "spring", context above is specified in "uses" section, so after code generation the context is being autowired and all the necessary checks are created in Impl class.

The following question raised: when the context is being cleaned/recreated? The mapper is stored in app's config class, so I guess that the context would be "living" all that time as well and it becomes too big and containing invalid entities after all the mappings. While I'd expected it to "live" during single map call.

For example, there is Entity1 (with context in uses section), which has Entity2 field, which is linked to Entity1 again. I'd expect context to be initialized before each top-level Entity1 mapping in order to avoid cycle dependency during Entity1.Entity2.Entity1 mapping. And it could be cleaned after the mapping is completed.

So, what's the actual logic regarding the context HashMap cleaning and how its overloading could be prevented?

Comment: Is there a reason why you annotate the context as component? The idea is to hand A 'fresh', empty context for each call to the mapper.  Note: the mappers are stateless intentionally

Comment: Mappers are spring components, I followed the instruction to specify context in "uses" section according to this - https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/469 - discussion.

Comment: True.. but context is not a mapper. IMHO it does not make sense to make a context a component

Answer (score 0):

The example you are referring to is part of the [mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles) and in there it is not used as a Spring bean.

The idea of the `CycleAvoidingMapperContext` is to be used as an `@Context` attribute.

You will create a new instance each time you pass it to the mapping method.

Comment: So are intending that such solution can't be used in spring beans? What's the solution for avoiding circular dependencies then?

Comment: I just linked to an example and wrote in the answer exactly how yiu can avoid the circular dependencies. You need to pass the context. As foe using a spring bean if you can find a way to clear such list in a singleton bean you can use it. A way would be to wrap the map into a `ThreadLocal`. However, I won't recommend that

Comment: In order to pass the context, it needs to be got from somewhere. In the respective discussion - https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/469 - there was an advice to specify context in uses section as well.

Comment: That issue reference the example repo I linked before. In order to pass the context you just need to instantiate and pass it to the map method (the same way you are passing the source). See https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/2001c1916c25a231caa394e395dab8920b50fca8/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles/src/test/java/org/mapstruct/example/EmployeeMapperTest.java